# Is there any way to let kernel use constant or global memory depending on data size

Tags: cuda

```
__constant__  float constbuf[MAXSIZE] 
__device__ float *d_buf;

__global__ void
simple (float *buf2){
   //access buf2;
}


main(){

   int size, asize;
   float *abuf, *d_buf2, *h_buf;
   //...
   if(size > MAXSIZE){
      cudaMalloc(&d_buf2, asize);
      cudaMemcpy(d_buf2, h_buf, asize);   
      cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_buf, &d_buf2, sizeof(d_buf2));
      cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **) &abuf, d_buf);
   }else{
      cudaMemcpyToSymbol(constbuf, h_buf, asize);
      cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **) &abuf, constbuf); 
   } 

   simple<<<grid, block, 0 ,stream>>>(abuf);


}
```

I want to do something like above, but I found in this way kernel didn't get correct buffer. Is there anyway to achieve this? I don't want to add "if" condition in the kernel if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution for this is to have one `__device__` kernel that does the bulk of the work and two `__global__` kernels that wrap the `__device__` kernel.

For example:

```
__constant__ c_buf[MAXSIZE];

__device__ simple_core(float *buf, int len)
{
 // do something here.
}


__global__ simple_global_mem(float *d_buf, int len)
{
    simple_core(d_buf, len);
}


__global__ simple_const_mem(int len)
{
    simple_core(c_buf, len);
}

int main()
{
 // other code

if (len < MAXSIZE) {
    // cuda memcpy to symbol code here
    simple_const_mem<<<threads, blocks>>>(len);
}
else {
    simple_global_mem<<<threads, blocks>>>(d_buf, len):
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If there is no simpler solution, I think I have to use this way